# How to sign an assembly using devenv.com

Tags: c#

HI,
Have a build process using devenv.com that will compile c# code into assemblies and this works as expected.
However I want to sign the assembly built using a key which I already have, is this possible?
I want to intergrate this into to the build process, do I need to use al.exe ?
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not in front of VS right now, but can't you add signing to your assemblies project properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the program you are after is sn.exe. This is used to sign an assembly using a strong name. See the [msdn documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: ok I was under the impression sn is for generating keps so I guess I was wrong.
Since I have compiled the dlls already without a strong name initially, can I still use sn.exe to sign it with my existing strong key or do I need to delay signing when compiling ?

Comment: I think you must delay sign them :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [sn.exe, the strong name tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [sn.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx), with the -R option

> Re-signs a previously signed or delay-signed assembly with the key pair in infile. 
>   If -Ra is used, hashes are recomputed for all files in the assembly.

Comment: OK, so when I compiled an unsigned DLL initially, is it still possible to use this method?
Applogies if it's a silly question.